# Problem with Datagrid View

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox

I am using datagrid view and i want to add datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Items gets added and display member is also showed if i debug and see them in watch but problem is that when form is showed datagrid view contains all other column along with this combo box but it is empty. why

```
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cbol.HeaderText = "Actions";
            cbol.Items.Add("Print Job Card");
            cbol.Items.Add("Print Invoice");
            cbol.Items.Add("Close Job Card");
            cbol.DisplayMember = cbol.Items[0].ToString();     
            cbol.Name = "bcolumn";            
            createCol = false;
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbol);
```

Comment: And how can we add event to this I mean when i select any of three items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a try, I created a new Winform application, I dragged and dropped a `DataGridView` on my Form, and in the `Form1()` method, I pasted your code (except the DisplayMember and createCol lines) :

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cbol.HeaderText = "Actions";
        cbol.Items.Add("Print Job Card");
        cbol.Items.Add("Print Invoice");
        cbol.Items.Add("Close Job Card");
        cbol.Name = "bcolumn";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbol);
```

It worked perfectly.

So my 1st question is: where do you use your code ?

2nd question if the 1st one doesn't help you: you see, in my code, `dataGridView1` is not in blue, because it's an instance of `DataGridView`. In yours, it is capitalized and it's in blue. Maybe there's something in there ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not set `DisplayMember`, since you aren't binding the combobox.

Comment: @Afrin: What is empty? The cell or the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was I had set ReadOnly attribute of datagrid view true thats why it did not allowed to do any change in real combobox was not empty